Issue with Unique ID Display in WPForms
I have a problem with the {unique_value} tag in WPForms. In principle, it displays a unique ID for each form submission. My issue is that this ID is displayed like "tUdJIeREikrxBhGz" as shown in the email received, but on the WPForms entries list, it displays as: "d2d34636-7427-42ce-8ed6-e2f6cb6dda40".
Thank you for your help
I tried to convert the second format into the first, but in vain

Welcome! This is not a good question for Stack Overflow. You should probably ask WPForms support team.

`<?php
/*

Create a unique 4-digit sequential number for each form submission using a custom counter.
*/

// Generate Unique Number Smart Tag for WPForms
function wpf_dev_register_smarttag( $tags ) {
// Key is the tag, item is the tag name.
$tags['unique_number'] = 'Unique Number';

return $tags;

}
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tags', 'wpf_dev_register_smarttag' );
// Generate Unique 4-Digit Sequential Number
function wpf_dev_process_smarttag( $content, $tag, $form_data, $fields, $entry_id ) {
if ( 'unique_number' === $tag ) {
    // Retrieve the current number from the database or set an initial value of 1000
    $current_number = get_option( 'wpforms_unique_number', 1000 );

    // Increment the number for the next submission
    update_option( 'wpforms_unique_number', $current_number + 1 );

    // Format the number to ensure it is always 4 digits (e.g., 0001, 0010, 0100)
    $unique_number = str_pad( $current_number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

    // Replace {unique_number} with the formatted 4-digit number
    $content = str_replace( '{unique_number}', $unique_number, $content );
}

return $content;

}
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'wpf_dev_process_smarttag', 10, 5 );
?>
`

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
